# One-sided derivative for a Lipschitz function and its limit

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(t)$ be a Lipschitz continuous function and let $ f'(t)=\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0 } \frac{f(t+\delta)-f(t)}{\delta}$ denote its one-sided right derivative in $t$.
Assume that $f'(0)$ exists. My question is about the equation:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{t\downarrow 0} f'(t).
$$
Is this equation necessarily true provided that the limit in the RHS exists?

In general, the equation above does not make sense because the RHS may not exists even when $f'(0)$ does, for instance $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, but if also the RHS exists, does it need to be equal to $f'(0)$?

Comment: [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux.27s_theorem) states that the ordinary (two-sided) derivative has the Darboux property. It seems that you could generalize the proof of Darboux's theorem to get an identical result for the right/left derivative (hope I am not wrong on this!). Also, every discontinuity of a Darboux function is essential. So I think the answer would be yes.

Comment: @theindigamer thanks for pointing out Darboux's theorem. However, I am kind of lost in understanding how to use it to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, the both side derivative exists almost everywhere and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies:
$$ f(t) - f(0) = \int_0^t f’(x) dx. $$

Let $a = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f’(x)$.
For $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $0< x < \delta$ it follows
$$ |f’(x) - a| < \epsilon. $$
Thus, we have
$$ \left | \frac{f(t) - f(0)}{t - 0}  - a\right| \le \frac1t \int_0^t |f’(x) -a | \le \frac t t \epsilon. $$
That is, the one-side derivative $f’(0)$ exists and is equal $a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've some difficulty in following your argument. If I understand correctly: firstly, you say that $f'(t)$ is continuous, but how that can be? $f'(x)$ may not even exists when $x$ belongs to some set of Lebesgue measure zero contained in the interval $(0,\delta)$. Furthermore, it seems that you assume that $a$ exists, which may not. Secondly, I cannot understand the last inequality.

Comment: @user52227 sorry, I have forgot $-a$ in the absolute value. As for the proof: **if** the one-side Limit $a=\lim_{t\downarrow 0} f’(0)$ exists, then $a$ is also the one-side derivative of $f$ at $0$.  If $a$ doesn’t exist, then your question makes not much sense.

Comment: ok for the existence of $a$. I'm sorry but I don't understand the last inequality. It may be stupid but since $f'(x)\neq (f(x)-f(0))/x$ I do not see how the last inequality is obtained...

Comment: @user52227 I extended the last inequality.

Comment: Now I see it, nice! Thank you!